# UIPanGesture in UIScrollview to Drag Object Vertically

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop, uipangesturerecognizer

I have added UIPanGesture to UIScrollView and Draggable object to it, for drag and drop functionality from UIScrollView to UIView,Everything working fine, but it's not working when O scroll the Draggable object Vertically instead the UIScrollView is Scrolling.

Any ideas? How can make UIScrollview on scroll while I'm dragging the object using UIPanGesture?

Comment: Hello Shaf Khan, I finding to understand what you are saying can you elaborate in more detail, if you are having difficulty expressing yourself in English try asking a friend for help or you could write on your native language in google translate and pasting it here in.